# How to create snapshot ISO-image from Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, snapshot, digital-ocean, iso

I intend to run computationally intensive calculations on expensive cloud servers. Setting up the environment (starting Ubuntu server via cloud API, downloading and installing Python/models, downloading input file) takes 10-15 minutes, which causes unnecessary costs at 0.025 cents per minute. I could save a few minutes with a Docker image.

However, I would gladly choose the path via my own server image. Unfortunately, I fail when trying to export a fully configured Ubuntu instance as an ISO image: Instructions on the Internet are limited to individual folders or require software with a GUI, which I would like to avoid in order to be able to automate this process later with a script.

Can anyone help me? Desirable would be a CLI command like `makeiso / ~/custom-ubuntu.iso`, the output file of which I can define as an image at cloud server providers.

Comment: Docker images are not made using iso files. Neither does an iso help you creating cloud instances. You should read the Docker documentation on how to build images.

Comment: iso and docker images are different and meant for different use cases. If you want to create ISO use any cloud platform and create ISO image directly via UI/CLI and you can download as well locally, some other way also available on internet to create iso directly from local machines, remember steps may differ based on os type.